# x:Bind ViewModel method to an Event inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm basically asking the same question as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752448/binding-to-viewmodels-property-from-a-template), but in the context of the newer `x:Bind`.

ViewModels' DataContext is defined like so

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:ChapterPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
```

So whenever I need to bind something I do it explicitely to the ViewModel like so

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.pageList, Mode=OneWay}"
```

However that doesn't work within templates

```
<FlipView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.pageList, Mode=OneWay}">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Image">
            <ScrollViewer SizeChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.PageResized}"> <-- this here is the culprit
                <Image Source="{x:Bind url}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Reading the documentation, I found that using `Path` should basically reset the context to the page, but this (`x:Bind Path=ViewModel.PageResizeEvent` didn't work either. I'm still getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`, which should mean that it doesn't see the method (but a null).

Image class:

```
public class Image {
    public int page { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int heigth { get; set; }
}
```

And in the ChapterPageViewModel

```
private List<Image> _pageList;
public List<Image> pageList {
    get { return _pageList; }
    set { Set(ref _pageList, value); }
}

public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, 
  IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState) 
{
    Initialize();

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}

private async void Initialize() 
{
    pageList = await ComicChapterGet.GetAsync(_chapterId);
}

public void PageResized(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    //resizing logic happens here
}
```

Comment: Does that models:Image class have a ViewModel property? If it doesn't and you're trying to refer to that same ViewModel you bound to `FlipView.ItemsSource`, then you'll not be able to access it that way, as the DataContext of the DataTemplate is now a models:Image object.

Comment: It does. The code works if I take out the `SizeChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.PageResized}"`. But I need to be able to adjust the size of the image in the size of the ScrollView, which requires me to access ViewModel properties from within the template.

Comment: Would you mind adding the code for that Image class?

Comment: have you been trying with old good Binding instead of x:Bind?

Comment: There is another problem: even if that Image class do have a ViewModel property, you cannot bind two events like that. You should be using [EventTrigger and Command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4897897/4905310) instead. But first, add the code for the Image class so we can answer that properly.

Comment: Added the class. I suppose Command would get around the problem since it's not defined within the Template though. I will give that a try.

Comment: @RTDev UWP doesn't support `x:Type` which I think `Binding` would need in this case.

Comment: You do realize that neither your VM and your Image class have that PageResized, right? Or is it hidden on a VM's base class?

Comment: I didn't mention it, because it's just an empty method. It's in the VM. I added it it to the description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have two problems here:

First, **trying to directly bind an event to a event handler delegate**

That will never work, simply put.
One way to handle an event on MVVM pattern is by using [EventTrigger and ICommand.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897897/4905310)
It requires a class that implements ICommand. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14181248/4905310) will help you if don't know how to do it. I'll call mine `DelegateCommand`.

Here's how I would refactor it in two steps:

1) Add a Command to the VM:

```
public class ChapterPageViewModel
{
    public ChapterPageViewModel()
    {
        this.PageResizedCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnPageResized);
    }

    public DelegateCommand PageResizedCommand { get; }

    private void OnPageResized()
    {  }
}
```

2) Bind that Command to the SizeChanged event with EventTrigger and InvokeCommandAction.

```
<Page (...)
  xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
  xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core">
    (...)
    <FlipView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.pageList, Mode=OneWay}" >
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Image">
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SizeChanged">
                            <core:InvokeCommandAction 
                              Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.PageResizedCommand }" />
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                    <Image Source="{x:Bind url}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
</Page>
```

*"But Gabriel"*, you say, *"that didn't work!"*

I know! And that's because of the second problem, which is **trying to x:Bind a property that does not belong to the DataTemplate class**

This one is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031725/why-cant-i-use-xbind-relativesource-self-in-a-data-template), so I´ll borrow some info from there.

From MSDN, regarding [DataTemplate and x:Bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210946.aspx#binding_object_xbind)

> Inside a DataTemplate (whether used as an item template, a content
>   template, or a header template), the value of Path is not interpreted
>   in the context of the page, but in the context of the data object
>   being templated. So that its bindings can be validated (and efficient
>   code generated for them) at compile-time, a DataTemplate needs to
>   declare the type of its data object using x:DataType.

So, when you do `<ScrollViewer SizeChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.PageResized}">`, you're actually searching for a property named ViewModel on the that `models:Image` class, which is the DataTemplate's `x:DataType`. And such a property does not exist on that class.

Here, I can see two options. **Choose one of them**:

**Add that ViewModel as a property on the Image class, and fill it up on the VM.**

```
public class Image {
    (...)
    public ChapterPageViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class ChapterPageViewModel
{
    (...)
    private async void Initialize() {
        pageList = await ComicChapterGet.GetAsync(_chapterId);
        foreach(Image img in pageList)
            img.ViewModel = this;
    }
}
```

With only this, that previous code should work with no need to change anything else.

**Drop that x:Bind and go back to good ol'Binding with ElementName.**

```
<FlipView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.pageList, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="flipView">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Image">
            <ScrollViewer> 
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SizeChanged">
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction 
                          Command="{Binding DataContext.PageResizedCommand
                            , ElementName=flipView}" />
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                <Image Source="{x:Bind url}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

This one kind of defeat the purpose of your question, but it does work and it's easier to pull off then the previous one.

Comment: That did the trick. And introduced other problem - inability to get the event arguments. However, it made me realize I was just making my life harder by reading the dimensions of the template children, when I could just as well (and much more easily) read the FlipView dimensions. And that Command example will surely be useful in the future too. Thanks!

Comment: @rancor1223 Well, that event args is an old problem for MVVM. So, [I'll just leave this here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205472/mvvm-passing-eventargs-as-command-parameter)